# How do I create a horizontal UICollectionViewLayout like this

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewdelegate

I am wondering how do we make a UICollectionViewLayout like this?

It seems to be a difficult thing to achieve. I am able to create a horizontal layout but I am unable to make the second cell onwards become small and stack on each other like the picture blow

[image: Horizontal Layout Like This]

Comment: You want to make first collection view or the second one?